# Use the Lookup activity result in a subsequent activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to write the output of a **Lookup Activity** to a **Blob** in the **Storage Account** using **Azure Data Factory V2**?

**Note:** The lookup Activity executes a simple query - (Select * from Emp) which returns a set of records (say 10 records). All these 10 records are to be copied into a Blob as a .json file)

Comment: Probably Lookup + Web (or Azure Functions) would do the trick.

Comment: I think of Lookup as a process-oriented activity rather than a data-oriented one. Wouldn't Copy be a better choice for reading from Source and writing to Sink?

Comment: @JoelCochran, Agree with you. CopyData would be the appropriate solution for that case.